# How do I create branching particles like lightning?

Tags: particles, hair

Working on a project that calls for multiple lightning-like strands all coming out of certain areas (vertex group-able) on one mesh object at the same time, and hoping I can do this with particles. Can model if absolutely necessary, but would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I recently watched this and I loved it... [Thunder tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_o48J7w61s)

Hope that is what you're looking for. :)

Comment: Checking... thx by the way :)

Comment: Not exactly what I meant, but learned ALOT. And I thought I was a pro... :)